# Where is the appropriate place to start background threads in C# WinForms applications?

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I want to start 2 background threads. One thread is acting as a server for a client and another thread is acting as a client for a server. This application is both a server and a client application. Should I start these threads in the Main() function before calling Application.Run()? Or should they be created after the main form is loaded? I'm trying to keep the UI and business logic apart from each other but I know that these threads will need to notify events to the form. What is the best coding practice for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they need to perform logic on the main form, you will need that logic to run on the thread the main form was created on. So both the client and server will need to have a reference to the main form so they can call either Invoke or BeginInvoke on it (depending on whether the code on the main form needs to be synchronous or asynchronous). Therefore, you should probably start the threads after the main form is loaded so you can pass a reference to it to the client and server.

Comment: So does that mean I need to pass a reference to the main form all over the business logic classes?

Comment: Only in the places where you might need to invoke code on the main form. I guess an alternative approach would be to have your main form exposed by some global class that all you business logic has a reference to, or a static class. In that case, you could create the threads in the `Main()` method. You would just need to check to make sure whatever property or method is exposing the main form is not returning null before invoking some code on it. Also, you should always check to make sure the form is not disposed before invoking code on it.

Comment: How would I go about setting up a global class containing the main form?

Comment: It depends on how your application is setup. Is everything in the same assembly or do you have multiple assemblies each containing different parts of the business logic? That will affect where the global class will need to be defined or if it is even possible. If things are in the same assembly or you have a common assembly that all others reference, you could do something like this: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/findcurrentappcontext.aspx but I would use a Singleton pattern instead copying the code exactly. Otherwise, you'd probably have to pass around the Form to all your business logic.

Comment: Could I put all of the threads and forms inside a custom ApplicationContext class? Is that appropriate?

Comment: That might be possible. I guess you'll need to try it and see if it gives you any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Start them at `Main()` before the UI is created.